# Prove for any positive integer $n$, $(4n)!$ is divisible by $2^{3n}\cdot 3^n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

**Problem**: Prove for any positive integer $n$, $(4n)!$ is divisible by $2^{3n}\cdot 3^n$

**Solution given by the professor**: $$4! = 2^3\cdot 3$$
$$(4!)^n = 2^{3n}\cdot 3^n$$
$$\frac{(4n)!}{(4!)^n}=\frac{(4n)!}{2^{3n}\cdot 3^n}$$

**My question**: The steps are pretty straightforward but I don't understand the last and most crucial step. For $\frac{(4n)!}{2^{3n}\cdot 3^n}$ to be an integer, we need $(4!)^n$ to divide $(4n)!$, is it a clear property of the factorial? How is it obvious?

Comment: Hint: if you write out $(4n)! = 4n \times (4n-1) \times (4n-2) \times \cdots \times 2 \times 1$, how many multiples of $4$ are there? How many multiples of $3$ and $2$?

Comment: @Wojowu  Practice donning a kinder tone. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is true that $(4!)^n\mid(4n)!$, but it is not obvious (at least, not to me). You can use the fact that, for any natural number $m$, $4!\mid m(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)$; after all$$\frac{m(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)}{4!}=\binom{m+3}4.$$So:

- $4!\mid1\times2\times3\times4$;
- $4!\mid5\times6\times7\times8$;
- $\vdots$
- $4!\mid(4n-3)\times(4n-2)\times(4n-1)\times(4n)$

and therefore $(4!)^n\mid(4n)!$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is clearer now. In the notes the professor said to use the multinomial coefficient and I think I understand now how it relates : $$\left( \begin{array} { c } { n } \\ { k _ { 1 } , k _ { 2 } , k _ { 3 } , \ldots , k _ { m } } \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array} { c } { n } \\ { \vec { k } } \end{array} \right) = \frac { n ! } { k _ { 1 } ! k _ { 2 } ! k _ { 3 } ! \ldots k _ { m } ! }$$

Each one of my $k_i$ would be equal to $4$, and since I have $n$ of those $4$, the sum of all the $k_i$ equal to $4n$. Which is precisely the multinomial coefficient.

Comment: That is quite nice!

Answer (score 1):

One can also use induction to show this. When $n =1$, the quotient is an integer$( = 1)$. Assume this is true for $n =k$ i.e., $(4k)!/(4!)^{k} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then for $n =k+1$ we can see that $(4(k+1)!)/(4!)^{k+1} = \{(4k+4)(4k+3)(4k+2)(4k+1)(4k!)\}/4! \times (4!)^{k}$
Then we need to prove that  $(4k+1)(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+4)/4!$ is an integer, which is indeed as  pointed out in above post.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The product of $k $ consecutive integers is divisible by  $k! $.

For proving the  above statement, consider the coefficients in binomial expansion.

Comment: Actually this is my next problem and this one I got it right:
Let the consecutive numbers be $n , n - 1 , \ldots , n - r + 1 .$ We have $$\frac { n ( n - 1 ) \cdots ( n - r + 1 ) } { r ! } = \left( \begin{array} { l } { n } \\ { r } \end{array} \right)$$.

Comment: Cheers! {}{}{}{}{}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Every product of $m$ consecutive integers is divisible by $m!$. Let $m=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Could proceed with  induction:

n=1: $$ (4n)! = 4! = (4!)^n $$
n=2: $$ (4n)! = 8!= 8(7)(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1) \mbox{ is divisible by } (4!)^n = 4^2(3^2)(2^2)(1) $$
Induction step: Assume that $(4!)^{n-1}$ divides $(4(n-1))!$

n: $$ \frac{(4n)!}{(4!)^n} = \frac{(4(n-1))! \, \times \, \mathbf{(4n-3)(4n-2)(4n-1)(4n)}}{(4!)^{n-1} \, \times \, \mathbf{4!}}$$ Notice that bold parts divide eachother trivially, and the non-bold parts divide by the induction hypothesis